# How to get the active SDK in VRTK?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vrtk

How do I get which set up SDK is currently active in VRTK? Or, even more helpful, how do I get the active camera and controller objects? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use this: 
VRTK_SDKManager.instance.loadedSetup.gameobject

VRTK_SDKManager.instance.loadedSetup.actualHeadset
VRTK_SDKManager.instance.loadedSetup.actualLeftController
etc.

Check This:
https://vrtoolkit.readme.io/docs/vrtk_sdkmanager